# I am so glad this site exists!

Tags: discussion

I just want to say that I'm really happy this site exists now. A place to ask and answer math questions intelligently, at any level, is greatly needed, and using the SE voting system to keep things clean, keep people accountable, and let the best answers filter to the top, is just what we need!

Thank you, internet!

Comment: You should show your appreciation by accepting an answer on your question!

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for reminding me. They're probably all "right" answers so it will be tough to choose, I think.